# HttpUtility.UrlEncode will not encode ! as %21

Tags: c#, .net, urlencode

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("!!!test", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"))
```

It doesn't encode `!` to `%21` - why?

Comment: As a workaround you can do a `.Replace("!","%21")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it is a [valid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547940#1547940) on a URL and doesn't need to be encoded.

Comment: but if i sniff a firefox, it encodes, also php function urlencode encodes too

Comment: @kusanagi - which means they are doing something that is not needed, at least when URL encoding is concerned. They may be doing that due to internal implementation considerations.

Comment: but server not accept '!' only '%21' so i need manually replace?

Comment: @kusanagi - What server? You didn't mention a server in your question.

Comment: http server, i make program post, so if i submit in firefox server accept '!' but my programm post request not accept

Comment: @kusanagi - What webserver? Did you attach a debugging proxy to see the actual request/response? Perhaps you should be asking a new question about this.

Comment: if i post value '!!!test' server get only 'test' but if i post'%21%21%21test' server get '!!!test'

Comment: @kusanagi - Looks like an issue with your web server or framework. It works fine on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!